# Creating Foreign key with string data type in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two tables. One is students_attendances and another is students. Now i want to set a foreign key between these two tables. And also I have string data type on which I wanna set foreign key but its giving me the error. Below is my code. Take a review of it ...

//students_attendances Table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students_attendances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('class_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('student_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('attendance');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('student_id')->references('student_id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');


        });
    }
```

//students table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('student_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('DOB');
            $table->integer('students_class_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('blood_group');
            $table->string('religion');
            $table->string('photo_id');
            $table->string('student_address');
            $table->integer('student_phone_no');
            $table->string('guardian_name');
            $table->string('guardian_gender');
            $table->string('guardian_relation');
            $table->string('guardian_occupation');
            $table->integer('guardian_phone_no');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('NIC_no');
            $table->string('guardian_address');
//            $table->string('document_id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your students table Change

```
 $table->string('student_id');
```

to

```
$table->string('student_id')->unique();
```

To be used as foreign key, it must be a unique key.

So, the new migration will be

```
Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->unique("student_id");
        });
```

Comment: in which table ?

Comment: Giving me the following error now **General error: 1005 Can't create table `sms`.`#sql-3378_54` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `students_attendances`
add constraint `students_attendances_student_id_foreign` foreign key (`student_id`) references `students` (`student_id`) on delete cascade)**

Comment: **Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'student_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `students_attendances` add unique `students_attendances_s
tudent_id_unique`(`student_id`))**

Comment: And I did something like this `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students_attendances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('class_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->unique('student_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('attendance');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('student_id')->references('student_id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');


        });
    }`

Comment: @HasnainKahn your table is already got created or you want to create fresh, if already created above solution will work, if you are regenerating, you need to specify in first migration only that will create the table, you do not need to add second migration.

Comment: Can we move to the chat room ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192954/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-hasnain-kahn).

Comment: Can we talk again. I have the similar issue again but a lil different

Comment: @HasnainKahn Yes, you can come to char.

Comment: Hello Sir can we please chat there ?